# How to assign a grid value to points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, vector-grid

I would like to create a grid (say 10mx10m) with unique values (i.e. grid 1,2,3,4) and then overlay a point file and assign a grid value to each point. All points within the first grid have field grid ID = 1 all points within the second grid have field grid ID = 2, etc.

I have created grids with `Xtools Pro> Create Fishnet` which have unique FID but haven't figured out how to get that associated with the point data.

Comment: Is the end result you are looking for strictly the ID on the points featureclass?  If so, this could be done much faster without creating a fishnet polygon featureclass.

Comment: Yes I think so. Each point with have a unique Grid/Cell ID corresponding to which Grid/Cell its located in.

Comment: @whuber I had seen that answer and I guess am looking for a canned ArcGIS function that will get the same result.  My math is rusty and that method made my head hurt. Maybe this is too advanced of a forum.